# Jquery replacing image url with html element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have this code

```js
let data.message = "message https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png"

$('<div/>').text(data.message).html().replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '<img src="$1">$1</a> ')
```

Idk why its not working it splits the line on my thing cause its a chat app but it splits the http s:// for some reason heres the code to go to next line:

```js
function getName(name) {
  let newName = name;
  // offsets i to match the current string
  let offset = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < name.length; i += 1) {
    if (i % 35 === 0) {
      if(newName.charAt(i) === ' ') {
        // Your own code with the offset
        newName = newName = `${newName.substr(0, i - offset)}\n${newName.substr(i - offset + 1)}`;
      } else {
        // looking back in the string until there is a space or the string "ends"
        while(newName.charAt(i - offset) !== ' ' && offset <= 35) {
          offset++;
        }

        // Only set newName if a space was found in the last 35
        if(i - offset > 0) {
          newName = `${newName.substr(0, i - offset)}\n${newName.substr(i - offset + 1)}`;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return newName;
}
```

Comment: `data.message` is always of the form `"message http://someurl.com"`?

Comment: data.message is what a user sends in chat so like it could be anything containing a url or not but if theres a url it replaces it with the string but adds a html element when it knows a url is there